# Overriding __getitem__

Tags: python-3.x, metaclass

I'm building a class and looking to make the following "numpy like" syntax work:

```py
#simple example
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.arr = [1,2,3,4]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.arr[index]
    
    def print_next(self,index):
        print(self.arr(index+1))

    def print_previous(self,index):
        print(self.arr(index-1))

a = MyClass()
a.arr[2].print_next() #4
a.arr[2].print_previous() #2
```

`__getitem__` only allows me to access the index and not the method call that comes after. I'm looking into metaclasses to change `__getitem__` but I can't figure out how to proceed.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are attempting in numpy?

Comment: Well the method call that comes after is a method for the class `MyClass`. If your goal is to then call a method liket hat, `__getitem__` would need to return `self`.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! Please remember to add as much information as possible to your question, the code that you provided won't run because of type errors, which are not described as part of your question. Also, it would be nice to explain what are you trying to achieve, and if possible show an example (maybe using NumPy as a reference?). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```py
In [86]: class MyClass():
    ...:     def __init__(self):
    ...:         self.arr = [1,2,3,4]
    ...:         self.index = None
    ...:
    ...:     def __getitem__(self, index):
    ...:         self.index = index
    ...:         return self
    ...:
    ...:     def print_next(self):
    ...:         print(self.arr[self.index+1])
    ...:
    ...:     def print_previous(self):
    ...:         print(self.arr[self.index-1])
    ...:
```

You don't actually need another argument for `print_next` or `print_previous` since you're hoping to call a method again.

Although this isn't recommended since you're overriding `__getitem__` to just return `self` and set a variable.

But now you can do this:

```py
In [90]: a[2].print_next()
4
In [91]: a[2].print_previous()
2
```

Comment: Thank you, it was simpler than I thought but I couldn't think of it. You answered my question perfectly !

Comment: No problem. You just might want to do some sanity checks within it as well. Like initialize `self.index = 0` and make sure that the next and previous items are within the range of valid indices.